# How to change the property values after getting from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, properties

Here is my code

```
 private bool isactive=true;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return isactive; }
        set { isactive = value; }
    }
```

I will get True,True,True,False,True,False for grid column from database .I want to replace True with Active and False with InActive in my Grid .
 like

```
 `if(isactive==true){isactive="Active"}` else{isactive="InActive"}
```

Instead of true false from db i want to put Active and InActive in my grid view display.
I trid it but no solution can u people help me through this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to have to use another property to display the values in your grid, because now you are trying to assign a `string` value to a `boolean` property.

```
private bool isactive=true;
public bool IsActive
{
    get { return isactive; }
    set { isactive = value; }
}
public string IsActiveText
{
    get { return IsActive? "Active":"Inactive"; }
}
```

Then use the property `IsActiveText` in your view like this:

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.IsActiveText).Title("Status");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate data in your `View` for eg

```
if(Model.IsActive==true)
 {
    <label>Active</label>
 }
else
 {
    <label>InActive</label>
 }
```

Comment: i din't got u  columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Title("Status");   This way i am binging to my kendogrid .

Comment: @Bart Beyers has given better answer try that Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You can update you view like this:

```
@if(Model.IsActive)
{
<span>Active</span>
}
else
{
<span>InActive</span>
}
```